# Show that $\int \frac{1}{x-z}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)$ exists on the upper half-plane if $\int (1+|x|)^{-1}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)<\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

In [Harmonic Analysis: A Comprehensive Course in Analysis, Part 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1470411024) page 62, he states a definition of Stieltjes transform of a finite (Borel) measure on $\mathbb{R}$:

> If $\mu$ is a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$, its Stieltjes transform, $F_\mu(z)$, is the function on (the upper half-plane) $\mathbb{C}_+$ given by
> $$
> F_\mu(z)=\int \frac{1}{x-z}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x).\qquad (*)
> $$

It is not difficult to see that this integral is well-defined. Later on page 64, he removed the assumption that $\mu$ is finite;

> For $F_\mu$ to exist, one only needs $\int (1+|x|)^{-1}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)<\infty$ ...

I want to know the reason behind it. I tried to find the upper bound of the integrand in (*) in different ways to see if somewhere can be at most $(1+|x|)^{-1}$, but no luck! Here is one of my tries: I write $z=u+iv$ with $v>0$, then
$$
\frac{1}{x-z}=\frac{x-u}{(x-u)^2+v^2}+i\frac{v}{(x-u)^2+v^2},
$$
Multiplying both sides by $z=u+iv$, we get
$$
\frac{z}{x-z}=\frac{ux-u^2-v^2}{(x-u)^2+v^2}+i\frac{vx}{(x-u)^2+v^2}\\
=\frac{u(x-u)-v^2}{(x-u)^2+v^2}+i\frac{vx}{(x-u)^2+v^2}\\
=\frac{u(x-u)/v^2-1}{\left ( \frac{x-u}{v} \right )^2+1}+i\frac{x/v}{\left ( \frac{x-u}{v} \right )^2+1}
$$
Then I get stuck ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $z=u+iv$ with $ v > 0$ is
$$
 x \mapsto \frac{1+|x|}{|x-z|} = \frac{1+|x|}{\sqrt{(x-u)^2+v^2}}
$$
a continuous function on $\Bbb R$ with limit $1$ for $x \to \pm \infty$. It is therefore bounded, so that
$$
\frac{1}{|x-z|} \le C \cdot \frac{1}{1+|x|}
$$
for some constant $C > 0$ and all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: That's interesting ... If you have shown that $|f(x)|\to 1$ as $|x|\to \infty$, wouldn't we get that for some $C>0$, we have $|f(x)|\leq C$ for all large $|x|$? What I don't understand, why this holds for "all $x\in \mathbb{R}$".

Comment: @James2020: Because it is a *continuous* function. If you have $|f(x)| \le K_1$ for $|x| \ge R$ then $f$ has a maximum $K_2$ on $[-R, R]$, so that $C = \max(K_1, K_2)$ is an overall maximum.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for your help